# New with Ruby on Rails, how to submit form with ajax in main view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, web

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I can't wrap my head around the routing stuff.

I have a main view (index.html.erb) with a basic subscribe form with main controller, I have a resource named User in routes.rb with an associated user controller.

/app/views/main/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @user, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
    <%= f.submit "Subscribe" %>
<% end %>
```

/app/controllers/main_controller.rb

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @user = Users.new
    end

    def create
        @user = Users.new(params[:user])

        respond_to do |format|
            if @user.save
                format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Thank you !' }
                format.js
            else
                format.html { render action: "new" }
                format.js
            end
        end
    end
end
```

/config/routes.rb

```
MyPage::Application.routes.draw do
  get "main/index"

  root 'main#index'

  resources :users
end
```

UsersController is empty.

I know I need to change something in routes.rb but I don't get it. I get uninitialized constant MainController::Users error. Thanks !

Comment: Where is your UsersController ?

Comment: /app/controllers but there's only the base class definition in it : class UsersController < ApplicationController
end

Comment: You're using a form that asks for the instance variable @user from the UsersController. So, In UsersController you need to write methods new, create, edit, destroy.

Comment: can you just move your `root 'main#index'` at last and restart your sever

Comment: and what should I write in those methods, only @user = Users.new or Users.delete ? if the form is in the main controller, can it know what User is without specifying something in the routes ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your `UsersController` is being confused as to inherit from `MainController`

---

This is either a routing issue or an issue with your system setup:

**Routes**

```
#config/routes.rb
root to: 'main#index'
resources :users, :main
```

**View**

```
<%= form_for @user, url: main_create_path, method: :post, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
    <%= f.submit "Subscribe" %>
<% end %>
```

**Controllers**

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @user = Users.new
    end

    def create
        @user = Users.new(params[:user])

        respond_to do |format|
            if @user.save
                format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Thank you !' }
                format.js
            else
                format.html { render action: "new" }
                format.js
            end
        end
    end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
 #your_stuff_here
end
```

Comment: this is where I am confused, what is UsersController supposed to do ? the methods in a controller are called by a url right ? since I don't want to change page, why should I define any actions in my UsersController ?